# Divide Spark DataFrame rows into multiple rows depending on the size of Map type column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

**Spark DataFrame Structure:**

```
root
 |-- partition_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- row_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- data_as_of_date: string (nullable = true)
```

`attributes` column is of type `map`. It can contain more than `65535` key value pairs.

I am writing the same DataFrame to Cassandra table. Table DDL as below:

```
create table <keyspace>.<table> (
  partition_key text,
  row_key text,
  attributes map<text,text>,
  data_as_of_date text,
  PRIMARY KEY (partition_key, row_key)
  );
```

**Issue:**
In Cassandra, the `map<text, text>` type column for `attributes` can not contain more then `65535` key value pairs.

**Question:**
Can someone please help me with the Scala-Spark snippet to divide a DataFrame row into multiple rows if the DataFrame map type column has more than 65535 key value pairs.

E.g.,
If the DataFrame row has 163838 key value pairs in the map type column, then the row should be divided into 3 rows. The `row_key` will have `_ + Seq No.` appended for that row, so that it generates unique Cassandra composite primary key after dividing the row into multiple rows. If the map type has <= 65535 key value pairs, then the row should not change.

The values will look like below:

```
<partition_key>, <row_key>_1, <65535 key value pairs from the map>, <data_as_of_date>
<partition_key>, <row_key>_2, <65535 key value pairs from the map>, <data_as_of_date>
<partition_key>, <row_key>_3, <32768 key value pairs from the map>, <data_as_of_date>
```

Please use the below sample DataFrame/code. Any row having map size greater than 2 should be divided into multiple rows.

```
val data = Seq(("123", "123001", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("123", "123002", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("123", "123003", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("456", "456001", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("456", "456002", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("456", "456003", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725")
    )

    val df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

The output DataFrame should be as below:

```
"123", "123001_1", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725"
"123", "123001_2", Map("key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4"), "20210725"
"123", "123001_3", Map("key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"
"123", "123002_1", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725"
"123", "123002_2", Map("key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4"), "20210725"
"123", "123002_3", Map("key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"
"123", "123003_1", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725"
"123", "123003_2", Map("key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4"), "20210725"
"123", "123003_3", Map("key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"
"456", "456001_1", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725"
"456", "456001_2", Map("key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4"), "20210725"
"456", "456001_3", Map("key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"
"456", "456002_1", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725"
"456", "456002_2", Map("key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4"), "20210725"
"456", "456002_3", Map("key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"
"456", "456003", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that consist in:

1. posexplode the map column
2. integer divide the position column into group column
3. groupBy to merge same group into map again
4. concat the row_key and group column

So I think this should give the expected result:

```
val data = Seq(("123", "123001", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      (123", "123002", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("123", "123003", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("456", "456001", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("456", "456002", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3", "key4" -> "value4", "key5" -> "value5"), "20210725"),
      ("456", "456003", Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2"), "20210725")
    )

val df = data.toDF("partition_key", "row_key", "attributes", "data_as_of_date")

val maxItem = 2

df.select($"partition_key", $"row_key", $"data_as_of_date", posexplode($"attributes"))
  .withColumn("group", $"pos".divide(maxItem).cast("int"))
  .groupBy($"partition_key", $"row_key", $"data_as_of_date", $"group")
  .agg(collect_list(map($"key", $"value")).as("attributes"))
  .withColumn("row_key", concat($"row_key", lit("_"), $"group"))
  .select($"partition_key", $"row_key", $"attributes", $"data_as_of_date")
  .show
```

Comment: Thanks. The DataFrame Row should be only divided into multiple Rows and row_key appended with sequence No. when the map type column (attributes) has the count more than maxItem. Else, there should be no change to the row. E.g. Row "456|456003|[key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2]|20210725" SHOULD STAY AS IT IS and NOT change to "456|456003_0|[key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2]|20210725". Kindly amend and help.

Comment: This is because most of my rows (99.99%) will have the count of attributes (map key-value pairs) less than the maxItem threshold and I would like to avoid the additional processing on those rows. Only rows which have attributes count > maxItem should do this additional processing. Can we somehow first check the count of attributes and process only if it is greater than maxItem? Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a straight forward way to do that and I don't a anymore time... Also, maybe you could not-do-that? I don't know your goal, but you could keep the original row_key and rename the group column as sub_row_key, then later use the it only when required?

Comment: Sure. Let me try to do this using df.map and write custom code in map function. Thanks for the help. I will mark your answer as correct.